# Simple urlrewrite rule to display without .php filename

Tags: url-rewriting

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

For example visiting www.example.com/mongolia/ will redirect to www.example.com/mongolia.php
But the above gives a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your directive doesn't work because it causes infinite internal redirections (mangolia redirect to mangolia.php which will redirect to mangolia.php.php and so on ... ) , your regex also need some modification.

this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/*$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it is giving an 'internal server error'

Comment: make sure you have mod_rewrite module enabled, if it is on, post the full content of your .htaccess so i can detect the source of the problem.

Comment: It is definitely on as I was experimenting with some other stuff

Comment: # Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/*$ $1.php [L, QSA]

Comment: oups, it's the space between flags that causes the error, should work like a charm now :)

Comment: Hi, that works unless I put a trailing slash in which case it knocks out my css http://l.andrewwelch/mongolia works http://l.andrewwelch/mongolia/ doesn't  - is there a way to excluding my css / images directory etc